# How to improve the complexity of HashMap iteration?

Tags: java, c++, data-structures, iterator, hashmap

I implemented a custom HashMap class (in C++, but shouldn't matter). The implementation is simple -

- A large array holds pointers to Items.
- Each item contains the key - value pair, and a pointer to an Item (to form a linked list in case of key collision).
- I also implemented an iterator for it.

My  implementation of incrementing/decrementing the iterator is not very  efficient. From the present position, the iterator scans the array of  hashes for the next non-null entry. This is very inefficient, when the  map is sparsely populated (which it would be for my use case).

Can anyone suggest a faster implementation, without affecting the complexity of other operations like insert and find? My primary use case is find, secondary is insert. Iteration is not even needed, I just want to know this for the sake of learning.

PS:  Why I implemented a custom class? Because I need to find strings with  some error tolerance, while ready made hash maps that I have seen  provide only exact match.

**EDIT**: To clarify, I am talking about incrementing/decrementing an already obtained iterator. Yes, this is mostly done in order to traverse the whole map.

The errors in strings (keys) in my case occur from OCR errors. So I can not use the error handling techniques used to detect typing errors. The chance of fist character being wrong is almost the same as that of the last one.

Also, my keys are always string, one word to be exact. Number of entries will be less than 5000. So hash table size of 2^16 is enough for me. Even though it will still be sparsely populated, but that's ok.

My hash function:

hash code size is 16 bits.

First 5 bits for the word length. ==> Max possible key length = 32. Reasonable, given that key is a single word.

Last 11 bits for sum of the char codes. I only store the English alphabet characters, and do not need case sensitivity. So 26 codes are enough, 0 to 25. So a key with 32 'z' = 25 * 32 = 800. Which is well within 2^11. I even have scope to add case sensitivity, if needed in future.

Now when you compare a key containing an error with the correct one, 
say "hell" with "hello"
1. Length of the keys is approx the same
2. sum of their chars will differ by the sum of the dropped/added/distorted chars.

in the hash code, as first 5 bits are for length, the whole table has fixed sections for every possible length of keys. All sections are of same size. First section stores keys of length 1, second of length 2 and so on.

Now 'hello' is stored in the 5th section, as length is 5.'When we try to find 'hello', 
Hashcode of 'hello' = (length - 1) (sum of chars) = (4) (7 + 4 + 11 + 11 + 14) = (4) (47)
= (00100)(00000101111)

similarly, hashcode of 'helo' = (3)(36)
= (00011)(00000100100)

1. We jump to its bucket, and don't find it there.
2. so we try to check for ONE distorted character. This will not change the length, but change the sum of characters by at max -25 to +25. So we search from 25 places backwards to 25 places forward. i.e, we check the sum part from (36-25) to (36+25) in the same section. We won't find it.
3. We check for an additional character error. That means the correct string would contain only 3 characters. So we go to the third section. Now sum of chars due to additional char would have increased by max 25, it has to be compensated. So search the third section for appropriate 25 places (36 - 0) to (36 - 25). Again we don't find.
4. Now we consider the case of a missing character. So the original string would contain 5 chars. And the second part of hashcode, sum of chars in the original string, would be more by a factor of 0 to 25. So we search the corresponding 25 buckets in the 5th section, (36 + 0) to (36 + 25). Now as 47 (the sum part of 'hello') lies in this range, we will find a match of the hashcode. Ans we also know that this match will be due to a missing character. So we compare the keys allowing for a tolerance of 1 missing character. And we get a match!

In reality, this has been implemented to allow more than one error in key.
It can also be optimized to use only 25 places for the first section (since it has only one character) and so on.
Also, checking 25 places seems overkill, as we already know the largest and smallest char of the key. But it gets complex in case of multiple errors.

Comment: I don't understand, when you try to find a value, shouldn't you immediately go to the first `Item` held in the array with the given key and then traverse a linked list?  If you are having to traverse the entire array then either your array is too small or your hash function isn't very good (the only way this should happen is if there are _tons_ of collisions).

Comment: @Jared I *think* (quite possibly incorrectly) that he's talking about iterating the *entire hash map*, not just one collision chain. Would be nice to know for better clarity, I concur.

Comment: Are you saying that you want something like `"hello"` and `"hwllo"` to me mapped to the same hash value (because they are similar--note that 'e' and 'w' could easily be accidentally typed for one another based on where they are on a QWERTY keyboard).  Thus you want a quick lookup to essentially group similar strings?  Because if you are saying look at every string and make a comparison (and find the closest one) then you aren't describing anything that could be remotely construed as a hash table.

Comment: @Jared I have updated the question with clarification. I want to improve iterating the entire hashmap. I don't want "hello" and "hwllo" to have the same hash value, but that when "hello" is stored and I try to find "hwllo", I should be able to reach "hello" efficiently. This part is already implemented, as now updated in the question.

Comment: @WhozCraig yes, your thinking is right. please check the updated question for detailed implementation.

Answer (score 0):

You mention an 'error tolerance' for the string.   Why not build in the "tolerance' into the hash function itself and thus obviate the need for iteration.

Comment: Yes, that is what I have done. I have updated the question with details. Actually I don't need to iterate through the whole array. But wanted to know ways to speed it up.

Answer (score 0):

You could go the way of Javas [LinkedHashMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html) class. It adds efficient iteration to a hashmap by also making it a doubly-linked list.

The entries are key-value pairs that have pointers to the previous and next entries. The hashmap itself has the large array as well as the head of the linked list.

Insertion/deletion are constant time for both data structures, searches are done via the hashmap, and iteration via the linked list.

Comment: Thanks. I thought of this, but how can insertion deletion be constant time? It will only be constant for the map. You will also have to search the key to be inserted/deleted in the linked list. (This will not be a problem when number of entries is small)